# TCP/IP client-server slow communication

Tags: linux, networking, ip, tcp, tcp-ip

I made some network application.
It is a client-server solution using the TCP/IP protocol.
Clients connect to the server.
They make several connections every second.
Communication consists of units of bytes that are read and written interleaved several hundred times in each connection.
And here is a problem in my application.
As the connection length (in bytes) increases, communication becomes unbearably slow (one request lasts 5 seconds).
I think the problem is with interleaving reading and writing of short pieces of data (about 8 bytes).

My program looks like this:

```c
fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if (setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (void *)&reuse, (socklen_t)sizeof(reuse)) < 0) {
    // ...
}

if (setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (void *)&reuse, (socklen_t)sizeof(reuse)) < 0) {
    // ...
}

init_sockaddr(&server_addr, serverport);

if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0) {
    // ...
}

if (listen(fd, 2048) < 0) {
    // ...
}

while (1) {
    int cl_fd = accept(fd, &sockaddr_in, &sockaddr_len);

    if (read_message(cl_fd, 0, ipv4) < 0) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In the `read_message` function, the problematic code is something like this:

```c
if (write_uint64(fd, n) < 0) {
    // ...
}

if (write_uint64(fd, TASK_SIZE) < 0) {
    // ...
}

if (read_uint64(fd, &clid) < 0) {
    // ...
}
```

The `write_uint64` sends 8 bytes, whereas `read_uint64` receives 8 bytes.
This code is typically repeated 128 times in a function for one connection.

My question is why interleaving reading and writing small pieces of data slows me down so much?
Is turning on `TCP_NODELAY` a bad idea?
What should be set on the TCP/IP connection so that writes and reads do not wait?

The full code is available [here](https://github.com/xbarin02/collatz/blob/master/src/server/server.c).

Comment: What is the round-trip time between your client processes and the server process?  The 5-second time you mention - is this for one 8-byte message sent and reply received, or for the full connection with 128 of the message/reply interactions?

Comment: Do you have `root` access to the server?

Comment: @SottoVoce Good idea. I will measure it and write it here. The 5-second time is for 128 message/reply interactions.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Yes, I do have.

Comment: I guess it would be a good start to determine whether the problem is on the server or "in the network". I suggest you run `tcpdump` and compare the time between an incoming packet and its response packet. If this time changes with the amount of data per connection then the problem is on the server. It it does not then some network node does not like this traffic.

Comment: @SottoVoce The round-trip time is mostly about 46.92 milliseconds. I guess that 47 ms times 128 message/reply interactions gives 6 seconds per one request. However, the RTT oscillates a bit between 47 and 7 ms. There are two ssh tunnels along the way. At the moment I don't know where to go next.

Comment: I rewrote the communication protocol so that it contains only one message/reply interaction for 128 requests. This seems to have solved the problem.